# Send variable _id to next file in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

```
int _id;
              List values = snapshot.data;
      return new ListView.builder(
          itemCount: values == null ? 0 : values.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            print(values[index]);
            return new Card(
                child:
                    new Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: <Widget>[
              new Image.network(values[index]["event_banner"]),
                  new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),),
              new Row(
                    children: <Widget>[

                  new Icon(Icons.location_on, color: Color(0xFF53DD6C)),
                  new Text("..."),
                  new Text(values[index]["venue"].toString()
                  )),
                ],
                  ),new Padding(padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),),
        new Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
            new MaterialButton(
                child: new Text("CHECK IN"),
            color: Color(0xFF53DD6C),

            textColor: Colors.white,

            onPressed: ()
            {
                          _id = values[index]["id"];
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  new MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => new Search ()));
                }),
```

I would like to send the variable _id to another class in flutter, through the Navigator, however I was wondering how to pass it??
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please post more code. `_id = values...` is invalid by itself.

Comment: It's better to provide more code :)

Comment: Please check my updates, thank you!

Comment: I'd suggest to walk through some tutorials. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RS36gBEp8OI should be a good start.

Comment: @HeyabRedda Do you mean send _id to Search page?

Comment: Phuc Tran Yes please

Comment: Please check my answer and let me know if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say we have 2 screens: FirstScreen and SecondScreen. Below example shows you how to send an integer number from FirstScreen to SecondScreen. It's actually simple, by passing the integer to the constructor of SecondScreen.

```dart
// first_screen.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_playground/navigation/second_screen.dart';

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  FirstScreenState createState() => new FirstScreenState();
}

class FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text("This is first screen!", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.red, fontSize: 20.0),),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
          child: new Icon(Icons.navigate_next),
          onPressed: () {
        Navigator.push(context,
            new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new SecondScreen(5)));
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

```dart
// second_screen.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  int id;

  SecondScreen([this.id]);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      body: new Container(
        child: new Center(
          child: new Text("This is the passed id: ${this.id}", style: new TextStyle(color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 20.0)),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.navigate_before),
          onPressed: () {
        Navigator.pop(context);
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry it works, I though I've deleted the post on time as I realised that it is working.

Comment: Great. Thanks. I see that you accepted my answer, but you didn't make vote. Anyway, hope the answer helps you a little bit :)

Comment: One more question, is it possible to implement it within a Stateful Widget? @Phuc Tran

Comment: Yes, of course. You will pass your id from FirstScreen to SecondScreen like what I did in the code. Then you can pass the id to the State of Second Screen. @HeyabRedda

Comment: Great! sort it! Thank you very much for your time and help!

Comment: Great to hear. Thank you!